# sub declaration visual Basic

Tags: vba, excel

I am really new with [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), so please forgive my slaughtering of the code. I'm trying to write a macro for excel (my first one), and I get "statement invalid outside of type block" (pointing at the first line). Here is my code:

```
Sub MakeHTMLTable()    
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
   endRow As Integer

For Count = 1 To 200
    For CountY = 1 To 200
      If (!ActiveSheet.Cells(Count, CountY).Value.IsEmpty) Then
       ActiveSheet.Cells(Count, CountY).Value = "<td>" + ActiveSheet.Cells(Count, CountY).Value + "</td>"
      End If
    Exit For
Exit For

For i = 1 To 200
    If (!ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value.IsEmpty()) Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "<tr>" + ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)
    End If
Exit For

For x = 1 To 200
    If (!ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1).Value.IsEmpty()) Then
        endRow = x
    End If
Exit For

For countAgain = 1 To 200
    If (!ActiveSheet.Cells(x, countAgain).Value.IsEmpty()) Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(x, countAgain).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(x, countAgain).Value + "</tr>"
    End If
Exit For
End Sub
```

I really don't understand, as the debugger fails on the line of computer generated code without even making it to mine. Have I missed ending an `If`" or `For` block?

I also realize that I'm probably reinventing the wheel. Any help on more appropriate built in functions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've got quite a few syntax errors in your code.

In `VBA`, local variables are declared with the `Dim` keyword.
So, the `endRow` declaration should look like this:

```
Dim endRow As Integer
```

`For` loops should end with the `Next` statement. So, your `For` loops should look like this:

```
For x = 1 To 200
    If (!ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1).Value.IsEmpty()) Then
        endRow = x
    End If
Next
```

`VBA` uses the keyword `Not` instead of `!`, so, your conditionals should look like this:

```
If (Not (ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value.IsEmpty())) ...
```

Try removing most of the code and adding it back in line-by-line until all of it works. The `VBA` syntax can be cumbersome for those who aren't used to it.

Comment: I've never seen IsEmpty used that way and I can't get it to work.  Should it be 'If Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(i,1).Value) Then'

Comment: @DickKusleika Thank you for that. I've got it working now, but it wouldn't compile for me either. Go figure, bad syntax, no work.